# Magento 1.9 coupon code being applied but total not updating

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a simple 20% discount coupon code setup in a Magento store. In the cart when the coupon is applied the discount amount is shown but the grand total does not update e.g.

Subtotal £23.95

Discount - £4.79

Grand Total £23.95

I have checked the 'Mage_Tax' module is enabled, re-indexed everything but it still isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed any modules which will effect the Total of Cart ? Because there must be a possibility of conflict of modules in your project .

Comment: Thanks I'm not quite sure which module it was but I uninstalled a couple of redundant ones and this fixed this issue.

Comment: Thats great :-)

Comment: @lnelson92 it's okay to answer your own questions, feel free to add your solution/answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: I have the same issue and I just downgraded my PHP from version 7.0 to 5.6 and it fixed the problem. :D